# Retrieve sorted data based on one numeric column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have a table like attached image in MySQL database.

[image: MySQL table]

I am trying to retrieve sorted data based on SUM(freight) column. For this i have used the below query.

**SELECT ShipCountry
FROM CountryDetails
GROUP BY ShipCountry
ORDER BY SUM(freight) ASC**

When i run this i am getting result like below.

[image: MySQL result]

If i run the below query i am getting result like below. It's fine.

**SELECT ShipCountry, ShipCity
FROM CountryDetails
GROUP BY ShipCountry, ShipCity
ORDER BY SUM(Freight), ShipCity ASC**

[image: Results]

Instead of this i need a result like below. In order by clause SUM(Freight) should consider only ShipCountry. It should not consider both ShipCountry and ShipCity. My Expected result is

[image: Tableau's result]

How to achieve this result through MySQL query?

in SQL we can achieve like below query.

**Select ShipCountry, ShipCity from Countrydetails group by ShipCountry, ShipCity Order by SUM(SUM(freight)) over(partition by ShipCountry), Shipcity Asc.**

We need equivalent query like this in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.ShipCountry, t1.ShipCity, t2.countrysum FROM CountryDetails t1 
  join ( select ShipCountry, SUM(freight) countrysum from CountryDetails 
       group by ShipCountry )
  as t2 on t1.ShipCountry = t2.ShipCountry 
GROUP BY ShipCountry, ShipCity 
ORDER BY countrysum ASC ;
```

It includes a subquery but should produce a separate line for each country-city pair.

Comment: Yes. The above query producing my expected result. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can `GROUP BY ShipCountry` and `GROUP_CONCAT` the cities as below

```
SELECT
    ShipCountry,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ShipCity ORDER BY ShipCity ASC) AS cities,
    SUM(freight) AS total_country_freight
FROM
    Countrydetails
GROUP BY
    ShipCountry
ORDER BY
    total_country_freight ASC
```

This will output

> Argentina | Buenos Aires
>
> Spain | Portland
>
> Norway | Butte, Stavern
>
> Italy | Albuquerque
>
> Portugal | Lisboa
>
> Poland | Elgin, Seattle, Walla Walla, Warszawa

While displaying, you can split the string with comma and print your expected output.